# Asynchronous C callbacks into Haskell code via FFI

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, callback, ffi

I'm currently trying to port parts of the Windows API to Haskell. One of the functions covered is `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` which registers a handler callback that is called whenever a Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break is received from console input. So here a small sample program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import GHC.ConsoleHandler
import Foreign
import System.Win32.Process
import System.Win32.Types

foreign import ccall "wrapper"
    makeHandlerPtr :: (DWORD -> IO BOOL) -> IO (FunPtr (DWORD -> IO BOOL))

foreign import stdcall "windows.h SetConsoleCtrlHandler"
    c_SetConsoleCtrlHandler :: FunPtr (DWORD -> IO BOOL) -> BOOL -> IO BOOL

main :: IO ()
main = unsafeCtrl

unsafeCtrl :: IO ()
unsafeCtrl = do
    ptrHandler <- makeHandlerPtr $ \d -> do
        putStrLn $ "received event " ++ show d
        return True
    c_SetConsoleCtrlHandler ptrHandler True

    forM_ [1..50] $ \_ -> sleep 100
    freeHaskellFunPtr ptrHandler

safeCtrl :: IO ()
safeCtrl = do
    installHandler $ Catch $ \e -> do
        putStrLn $ "received event " ++ show e

    forM_ [1..50] $ \_ -> sleep 100
```

If you compile the above program via `ghc --make AsyncCallback.hs` and run the program, it crashes with the following error as soon as a control event is received:

```
$ AsyncCallback
AsyncCallback.exe: schedule: re-entered unsafely.
   Perhaps a 'foreign import unsafe' should be 'safe'?
```

However, compiling with the `-threaded` option added seems to work fine:

```
$ AsyncCallback
received event 0
received event 1
received event 0
```

Not sure why this makes it work, as I don't explicitly use threads here, and I can't see where GHC would implicitly start a new thread.

Asking earlier about this on #haskell, someone noted that calling Haskell functions asynchronously from a C callback is inherently unsafe and that the above example just more or less coincidentally works. I was also pointed to `GHC.ConsoleHandler.installHandler` which seems to be a safe wrapper around `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, and running the above program with `main = safeCtrl` indeed works fine. I tried to understand the implementation of `installHandler` ([C-side](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/rts/win32/ConsoleHandler.c) and [Haskell-side](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/src/GHC/ConsoleHandler.hs)) but I don't quite get it.

The whole problem here seems to be that the callback is issued asynchronously, such that the Haskell RTS isn't "prepared" for when the callback tries to run the Haskell code. So I would like to know

1. How does the GHC implementation of `installHandler` work? What is the crucial part that makes that implementation work and my version fail?
2. Are there other options/general patterns how to call Haskell code asynchronously from a C callback? In this particular case, I can switch to the GHC implementation. But I may come accross similar C functions that asynchronously call back into Haskell code where I would have to write a safe binding on my own.

Comment: This isn’t intended to be a complete answer, but it looks like the console handler will just note that an interrupt was received, and then does something with the scheduler to make it do something at the next available opportunity. Take a look at [`Schedule.c`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/rts/Schedule.c), with a particular focus on `interruptStgRts` and how it interacts with the other functions in that file.

Comment: Looking at that file didn't give me any new insights, tbh. I've tried to find other Haskell libraries that use callbacks to see how they handle it. There is, for example, [`addTimerCallback`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.7.0.10/src/src/Graphics/UI/GLUT/Callbacks/Global.hs) from the GLUT package which also seems to just run the pure Haskell action, without the need for special handling from the C side or by RTS internals.

Comment: The reason the GHC implementation works is [this](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/rts/win32/ConsoleHandler.c#L183) - instead of calling the `FunPtr` inside the callback, the callback is passed as a `StablePtr` which is applied to a buffer of events captured by `generic_handler`, and (perhaps critically) this buffer is declared in the C file globally, making it properly available to the callback. You would probably have to find a similair approach (write to a buffer, consume from the buffer).

Comment: @user2407038: So do I understand correctly that it is the handling that happens in the critical section that makes the callback safe, because it kind of prepares the RTS for a safe re-entry to the Haskell side? To me this all looks awfully complicated compared to e.g. the much simpler `addTimerCallback` in the GLUT package, and I don't see why you need all the fancy C wrapping for the one callback but, apparently, no special handling for the other.

Comment: @siracusa `addTimerCallback` is GLUT, this is WinAPI you are working with. Blame Windows, not C. Seriously, I've only ever had this problem with WinAPI callbacks - the reason, I believe, is that the WinAPI uses the `stdcall` call convention, but GHC can't generate such a `FunPtr`. When you call a function with the FFI typically, the haskell RTS will be the one to clean up the stack (i.e. make the function conform to the call convention) but when such a function is called in a callback by the WinApi, the Haskell RTS gets no chance to even know it runs.

Comment: @siracusa Furthermore, why it works with `-threading`, I'm not too sure - perhaps with this flag, the Haskell RTS somehow registers foreign code in some way to be able to know when it runs? This is pure speculation - I don't know the GHC internals that well.

Comment: In the specific case of `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, the handler is called on a different thread. (This is different from how it works on POSIX platforms; see Raymond Chen’s [blog post on the subject](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080728-00/?p=21453/).) Hence, you either need `-threaded` so Haskell can, well, deal with threads; or, you can leave it to the RTS, which in C enqueues the event to be handled by the main thread when it’s free to do so (with no Haskell code ever running on the interrupt thread).